# Exploding string after removing whitespace

Tags: php

I am trying to process copied text from a website.
I am using iMacros to get the content from table and extracted data has lots of spaces between data.

I was trying trim and str_replace to remove spaces and it works but the problem I have is that when I am trying to explode new string, it looks like I am exploding original one, before trimming! Array has hundreds of keys!

What I am doing wrong?

Sample data:

```
"1","
                        Data1









                    ","
                                                            Data2
                    ","                                 
                                Data3
                    ","-","-1","-","-","-","-"
```

Here is a code that I'm using:

```
$data_lines = preg_split( '/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['data'] );

foreach($data_lines as $data_line) {

    $data_line = str_replace('  ', '', $data_line);
    $data_line = str_replace('"', '', $data_line);

    $data_line = explode(',', $data_line);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data_line);
    echo '</pre>';

}
```

So the goal is to get Data values and symbols/numbers in quotes (obviously whiteout the quotes) in array.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: added, but obviously is not working. Just a simple code to process data.

Comment: Can you please post an example of your desired output.

Comment: Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => Data1
        [2] => Data2
        [3] => Data3
        [4] => -
        [5] => -1
        [6] => -
        [7] => -
        [8] => -
        [9] => -
    )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$data = explode(',', preg_replace(
  array('/\r\n|\r|\n/', '/"\s*(\S*?)\s*"/'), 
  array(''            , '$1'              ),
  $_POST['data']
));
```

[working example](http://ideone.com/N6zczP)

Answer (score 0):

Use Trim function in php

```
trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string - php.net
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: trim is working initially but then after exploding is the same problem

Comment: Isnt it possible to use the trim function after the use of explode function. when you are looping through the $data_line array try the trim ?